# How can I export data from Excel to mysql?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Can this code be run on personal.xlsb (MS Excel) to transport data to mysql?

I get blank rows.

```vb
Public Sub Insert_Testing()
Dim con as adodb.connection
Dim lastrow as long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set con = New Adodb.connection
Con.open = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=MySQL_db;"
Dim rng as range
Lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(x1Up).row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:G" & Lastrow)
Dim row as range

For each row in rng.rows
    SQL = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px) values ('" & row.Cells(1).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(2).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(3).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(4).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(5).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(6).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(7).Value &'");"
    Con.Execute SQL
Next row

Con.close

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

This seems to not work since active sheet here keeps referring to my personal.xlsb and not the other document I am planning to export the data with as both documents are opened at the same time.

Comment: Can you share the Mysql Table Structure?

Comment: Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px these are the headers

Comment: U can help me by putting dummy values to the headers on an excel file then run this macro using personal.xlsb file (separate file from the previous one) for a start

Comment: mysql table structure - meaning data types of the columns - not just the column names

Comment: they are all numbers so can put varchar(45)

Comment: The line starting with `SQL=`... looks like your escaping of quotes is not correct.

Comment: weird enough this code can run perfectly if i don't use personal.xlsb (like if i use it on the same excel file). Do u have any advice on this? as well as the escaping quotes one?

Comment: I think I realised the problem. It is the difference is between "active worksheet" and the actual name of the worksheet like worksheet("X") bc I wanna do automation so how shld i refer to the worksheet i want if i do not open it/that it is not active?

Comment: You should refer to Excel VBA docs for that. Been long time away from VBA. Just here looking at Sql questions :)

Comment: Try just `Set ws = ActiveSheet`, if you want to refer to a worksheet from a workbook that's opened but not active (i.e. a fixed workbook) then you need to refer to it's workbook first either by a fixed reference (e.g. if fixed file name then `Workbooks("filename.xlsx")`) or if you opening it, set to a workbook variable when you open it by code (`Set wb = Workbooks.Open('filename.xlsx")`). Once you have the workbook variable then refer to its worksheet by index or name @GracellaQSumarlin

Comment: but what if none of the workbook will be active and since I am looping through the excel files in a folder so i do not have a fixed file name for it because new excel files keep uploaded every day?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
SQL = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px) values ('" & row.Cells(1).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(2).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(3).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(4).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(5).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(6).Value & '", '" & row.Cells(7).Value &'");"
```

to this:

```
SQL = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px) values ('" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(2).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(3).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(4).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(5).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(6).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(7).Value & "');"
```

Your Personal xlsb probably have other functions/vba code that is interfering. I am only guessing.

Comment: oh yes correct this is my code i retyped it wrongly bc jn i was using my phone thank you!

Comment: @GracellaQSumarlin So the answer was helpful? ;)